# What is the name of this part in plants, fruits, vegetables?

Tags: botany, terminology, fruit

What is the name of this part of the plant, fruit, vegetable? The thing that the plant is connected with the tree and gets nutrients with? The part we usually cut out when eat fruit.

Examples below

Papaya
[image]

Banana
[image]

Mango
[image]

Comment: google the word stem.

Comment: @John that's not a stem. What is the name of the plant part that stem gets into in the plant. This part of the fruit is not a stem.

Comment: @John I googled, it shows science, technology, engineering and mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Stalk' or 'pedicel' would be an appropriate term (see, for example, [this paper](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/337231) or [this one](https://academic.oup.com/jxb/article/56/420/2713/530534)). Specifically, you could say 'terminal part of the stalk/pedicel', though I don't know if there is a word for that.

Note that the term [pedicel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedicel_(botany)) is commonly used for the stalk of a flower; it makes sense to use it for fruits too as they are derived from flowers.